# Add TCP logger to existing windows service without rebuilding

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have a windows service running in a production environment that I need to perform some diagnostic work on. The service listens on a specified port, receives and processes a TCP request, and issues a TCP response.

What I'd like to do is intercept this request and response so I can log it to a database. However I cannot recompile the code and need to make as few changes to the server as possible.

I seem to recall a past instance where a colleague was able to create an interceptor DLL and drop this into the root folder of a WCF or Web API service in order to accomplish a similar task. Would it be possible to accomplish something like that with this TCP service?

Comment: Point your incoming requests to hit your interceptor, then forward the requests to the existing service.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting idea. So in this situation I'd create a new service that listens on the existing port, and reconfigure the existing service to listen on a new port?

Comment: Yes, or change (at the firewall) your incoming requests to to hit the interceptor's port. That is if you cant change the existing service's listening port. Either way, this is similar to a proxy server, I think there are examples out there in C#.

Comment: Why does it need to go in a database? My point is: why not just use Wireshark, or whatever the Microsoft equivalent (I don't recall the name) is?

Comment: I do not want to install any more software on the server than is necessary. Also I need to capture and manipulate the data at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the app uses `System.Net.Socket`, you can use the built in .net network tracing via `app.config`, docs from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing).

Adding source `System.Net.Socket` and `System.Net` with `maxdatasize` 1024 will cause it to log the first 1024 bytes of each send and receive.

Comment: I think this may be exactly what I was looking for. I'll give a look and see how that works.